# Throughput differences in bidirectional UDP communication

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, udpclient, throughput

I found a crazy behavior in my app + my network. I wrote a simple application that send and receive UDP packets (all with 968 bytes). Using three machines (A, B and C), all in the same local network (no firewalls), I have the following enviroment:

1. In the machine A the app sends 1 packet/ms to the app instances in the machines B and C.
2. In the machine B the app sends 1 packet/ms to the app instances in the machines A and C.
3. In the machine C the app sends 1 packet/ms to the app instances in machines A and B.

The app, beyond send packets, counts the received packets from each remote instances (time window=one second), this results in:

1. In the machine A the app shows receive 6.4% from machine B and 98%-100% from machine C.
2. In the machine B the app shows receive 98%-100% from both machines B and C.
3. In the machine C the app shows receive 6.4% from machine B and 98%-100% from machine A.

All the machines are using the same app version, so obviously there are any crazy thing, but using ipperf in a fast test no was possible see any problem in machine B. My code to send UPD packets is:

```
Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(peerContext.Address, this.sendPort);

while (mycondition) //this is a thread loop...
{
  byte[] buffer = (byte[])this.udpPacket.Clone();
  var sent = sender.SendTo(buffer, endPoint);

  if (sent != buffer.Length)
    //Warning.... never happen!
}
```

Using a 20ms rate I see the machines A e C receiving 64% (before was 6.4%) from machine B, but with iperf this doesn't happen.

And then, anybody can help with some ideia?

Comment: I'd start looking at machine B send side, as both A and C are receiving less, which makes B-send function the suspect.  Beyond that it could be a lot of things... cabling issues?  Is the switch it is connected to a managed switch (you can then try to see how many packets the switch sees coming from B)...

Comment: You may have resource contention while sending and receiving. Do you get the same results if you slow down your packet output to say 100ms?

Comment: @LB2, thank you by comment. I think that there aren't problem in machine B, using the ipperf I don't see problems. The thing is more obscure!

Comment: @hyru, thank you by comment. Using a 20ms rate I see the machines A e C receiving 64% (before was 6.4%) from machine B. Can be contention, but why only with my app and not with ipperf also?

Comment: I noticed, using wireshark, that the above code running in the machine B reached the max of 64 packets/second, no more, this number is "emblematic", but whyyyy? :(